# Joining Three Tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm trying to take data from three different tables and output it using as few queries and as little PHP code as possible.

Listed below are the tables I have and the columns in each (only listing relevant columns).

**exp_members (A)**
columns: member_id, group_id

**exp_brandrelations (B)**
columns: member_id, brand_id

**exp_du_mktgmats (C)**
columns:  du_id, brand_id, date

I want to loop through the members who belong to group_id='5' (from A), determine which brands are assigned to each member (from B), and get a list of du_ids (from C) that correspond to each member, that have been INSERTed in the last 24 hours.

So far, I can get a list of members in group 5:
    `SELECT member_id, brand_id FROM  exp_brandrelations`
    `WHERE member_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM exp_members where group_id = 5)`

And I can get a list of du_ids from the last 24 hours:
    `SELECT du_id FROM exp_du_mktgmats`
    `WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

But I'm not sure how best to tie it all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it!

```
SELECT m.member_id, b.brand_id, d.du_id FROM exp_members m, exp_brandrelations b, exp_du_mktgmats d WHERE m.group_id = '5' AND m.member_id = b.member_id AND b.brand_id = d.brand_id AND d.date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: This is what I needed...  until I decided I needed to JOIN in 2 more tables :p  but this did get me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT du_id FROM exp_members m, exp_brandrelations r, exp_du_mktgmats a
WHERE a.brand_id=r.brand_id AND r.member_id=m.member_id
AND date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND m.group_id='5'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    c.du_id
FROM 
    exp_du_mktgmats c
LEFT JOIN
    exp_brandrelations b
ON
    c.brand_id = b.brand_id
LEFT JOIN
    exp_members a
ON
    b.member_id = a.member_id
WHERE
    a.group_id = 5
AND
    c.date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```